# facing exception after removing tab bar from app

Tags: iphone, ios4

I added UITabBarController in my app but removed after some time. App was working fine before adding UITabBarController but when I removed it from app, I started facing below exception.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<XpensesAppDelegate 0x4daaa40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tabBarController.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fa45a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010f8313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00fa44e1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x00035677 _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 135
    4   Foundation                          0x000355e5 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 285
    5   UIKit                               0x004b930c -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 112
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00f1a8cf -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 239
    7   UIKit                               0x004b7d23 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1041
    8   UIKit                               0x004b9ab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x002bf17a -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 172
    10  UIKit                               0x002bfcf4 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 291
    11  UIKit                               0x002ca617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    12  UIKit                               0x002c2abf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x002c7f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x018fc992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00f85944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00ee5cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00ee2f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00ee2840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00ee2761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    20  UIKit                               0x002bf7d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    21  UIKit                               0x002cbc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    22  Xpenses                             0x00001ad9 main + 121
    23  Xpenses                             0x00001a55 start + 53
    24  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called throwing an exceptionsharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
```

Any solution to get rid of this exception?

Answer (score 1):

You have something connected to the `tabBarController` outlet of your app delegate in Interface Builder. However the outlet no longer exists, so you're getting this error. You should just find and remove that connection.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have been removed the tabBarController outlet and connection with app delegate but still facing same issue. app delegate connection inspector status is as follows.

Comment: app delegate connection inspector status is as follows.  [outlet] windows --- window. [referencing outlet] delegate --- file owner. There is no connectivity except these 2.

Comment: Well, if you're getting the same error I have to say I don't believe you :)

Comment: :), but it is like bitter reality. Any other suggestion do u have or I should start my app from scratch?

Comment: Perhaps try cleaning your project (⇧⌘K) and rebuilding it.

Comment: Now it is working fine. I closed project, quit from Xcode and deleted files manually from Library --> Developer --> Xcode --> DerivedData. And in Simulator select iOS Simulator --> Reset Content and Settings.